# How to insert pdf file into database using php through multiple page?

Tags: php, pdf

I have to select a pdf file in my step1 page then go to step2 page fill in other details. Once the form is submitted, all the data should be stored into database. 
The error showed: Undefined index pdf_file 
Here is my coding ..

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label><i class="zmdi zmdi-upload"></i></label>
    <input type="file" name="pdf_file" id="pdf_file" accept="application/pdf" />
  </div>
```

Step2.php

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "","db");
$pdf = $_POST['pdf'];

if(isset($_POST['confirm'])){
    //upload file
    $allow=array('pdf');
    $temp=explode(".", $_FILES[$_POST['pdf_file']]['name']);
    $extension=end($temp);
    $uploadfile=$_FILES[$_POST['pdf_file']]['name'];
    $appID="A0003";
    $sql=mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO application_table  (appID, pdf) VALUES ('$appID','$uploadfile')");
    if($sql){
        echo "okay";
    }else{
        echo "failed";
    }
}
```

What mistakes I made?

Comment: Save only path file, not file itself

Comment: What went wrong? If you don't tell us what happened, how can we help?

Comment: You could try the SQL query in the database console (and maybe add a tag, such as [tag:MySQL]), that might give a meaningful error message. also, learn how to for those parameters to the query, for security reasons.

Comment: the problem is "Undefined index pdf_file" for these $temp=explode(".", $_FILES[$_POST['pdf_file']]['name']); and $uploadfile=$_FILES[$_POST['pdf_file']]['name']; line.

Comment: And why is the problem not [edit]ed into your question? "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers." ([from the **Help**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))

Comment: `$_FILES[$_POST['pdf_file']]['name']` should probably be `$_FILES['pdf_file']]['name']`. See the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for the structure of the `$_FILES` array.

Comment: @KarstenKoop even i had changed to $_FILES['pdf_file']]['name'] the error stil the same. Undefined index: pdf_file